# Windows 7 edit control, vertical scroll does not work

Tags: winapi, windows-7, scroll, editcontrol

I have an application that compiles ok (mingw) and runs ok, however the edit control that is created has scroll bars but the vertical scroll bar doesn't do anything. The same executable works fine on WinXP. Also, the edit control has both vertical and horizontal scroll bars, the horizontal works just fine, but vertical does not. The vertical scroll bar is visible and clickable, but nothing happens...

Following code is used when creating the edit control:

```
HWND hwndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("Edit control"),
    WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE |
    ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_SIZEBOX,
    1000, 480, 400, 500, NULL, 0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
SendMessage(hwndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) TEXT("")); 
SendMessage(hwndEdit, EM_LIMITTEXT, 0, 0);
```

Following code is used repeatedly to add text to edit control:

```
char test[] = "test";
SendMessage(hWndDbg, EM_SETSEL, 0x7FFFFFFF, 0x7FFFFFFF); // Undo any selection and move to end.
SendMessage(hWndDbg, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM) temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the fix. It seems in WinXP the edit control does not have to have a parent window defined, in Win7 it is required for the vertical scroll bar to work, horizontal scroll bar works in Win7 even without parent window defined.

Answer (score 0):

Note that vertical scroll bars even make sense on single-line edit controls. In this case, WM_VSCROLL must be set, and ES_AUTOVSCROLL not. (EM_AUTOVSCROLL means EM_AutoHIDEVScroll.) The alternative UpDown control makes more programming efford than capturing VM_VSROLL messages, and then changing the (typically numerical) value inside the edit control.

Unluckily, the MS Visual Studio built-in Resource Editor won't let you add WM_VSROLL to single-line edits! You must do this by adding this bit by editing the .RC file in text mode.
Similar to the fact that this Resource Editor won't let you add a default text to the control, which is still supported by the resource loader.

Comment: Don't mess WM_ and WS_, EM_ and ES_ prefixes. ES_AUTOVSCROLL has nothing to do with hiding or showing the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetDesktopWindow() as hWndParent parameter. It works on Win7.